# Dict Comprehension With Class Objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dictionary of employee names as keys with values of objects of class FullTime. The one line of code I thought I would need for this was:

```
staffClassDict = {employee: FullTime(employee) for employee in staffList}
```

However, the dictionary is not created when I use this code, leading to a lot of key errors throughout the program. If I replace the `FullTime(employee)` with 0, the list is made without a hitch. Is there any way to achieve dict comprehension using objects, or should I just stick to a more traditional for loop?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that particular line of code. I think something else is wrong.

Comment: How isn't it created? Can you post the traceback?

Comment: Can you give a full program that doesn't work?

Comment: You guys were right -- I forgot that in the initialization of FullTime I had something that accessed a dictionary that I declared below my dict comprehension code... just had to switch the order of two lines and I was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
>>> class FullTime(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "FullTime(%r)" % self.name
...
>>> staffList = ["Alice", "Bob", "Eve"]
>>> staffClassDict = {employee: FullTime(employee) for employee in staffList}
>>> staffClassDict 
{'Bob': FullTime('Bob'), 'Alice': FullTime('Alice'), 'Eve': FullTime('Eve')}
```